# How to know the exactly total of current connections to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

My Azure PostgreSQL server has total connections is 480.

I want to check the total of current connections is accessing to database by perform below SQL:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

I can see the output list includes all users (superuser,...) and with idle and active status. So is this correct to check total of current connections? Or I should exclude "idle" connections to know the exactly the result?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 3):

"idle" connection is real connection. Because Postgres has not any internal executor pool (like thread pool of MySQL), any "idle" connection can process any commands. At this moment, the "idle" connection doesn't require too much sources, but when you calculate save memory limits (against using swap), you should to calculate with "idle" connections too - because any connection can be active connection sometimes.

480 connections is usually much - good number is 10-20 x CPU cores for `max_connections`. If you have too high `max_connection`, then you have to have low `work_mem`, what can has negative impact on performance, or your configuration should not be safe against overloading.

```
share buffers + (max connection * work_mem * 2) + ram for operation system
              + ram for filesystem < RAM
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so useful. Assume that from the pg_stat_activity, I have 480 connections (include idle connections), so other users unable to access to database as connection is full?

Comment: You have to know, what is your `max_connection` limit. After this limit users cannot to connect to Postgres. I strongly advice to set this value realistic. Is better to disallow connections than to have overloaded server. If you need high numbers of connections, use pgbouncer or pgpool.

Comment: Yes, I know about max_connection limit of course. Just concern Postgres will sum total current connection include idle? I also check, many idle connections are still there. We may need to set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout in Postgres

Comment: idle session is session (connect) - there are not a exception